# Base64encode bytes-like object is required in python3

Tags: python

My code is:

```
_cmd = "|| echo " + base64.b64encode(args.cmd) + "|base64 -d|bash"
   p.update({"form_284": _cmd})
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openemr_rce.py", line 136, in <module>
    _cmd = "|| echo " + base64.b64encode(args.cmd) + "|base64 -d|bash"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Edit:

There is no problem when you run it in python2

Comment: `args.cmd` is a `str`, it should be a `bytes` object to make it compatible with base 64 encoding. Without knowing where it came from, we can't know why it's the wrong type. A [MCVE] is needed for a complete answer.

Comment: Heh. I wonder if you're playing the same CTF where I recently saw OpenEMR used as a target...

Comment: Yes @CharlesDuffy . This is openemr_rce partial in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `args.cmd` is a string.

If it was meant to be, try `base64.b64encode(args.cmd.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")`.

If your command contains non-ascii characters, the bash cmd is on a system-dependent encoding, and you can use `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to fetch it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not encoding the base64, I'm encoding the input to the base64 which can be anything.

Comment: @vortext what do you mean? What was wrong with the solution?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openemr_rce.py", line 136, in <module>
    _cmd = "|| echo " + base64.b64encode(args.cmd.encode("ascii")) + "|base64 -d|bash"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: If the solution helped you, you can choose to accept the answer by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. For more info, see the [help manuals](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @vortext Indeed, you need to decode the answer as well. Updated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you must pass a "bytes-like object" to `b64encode`, not a string. To get bytes from a string, you can call `encode()`:

```
base64.b64encode(args.cmd.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openemr_rce.py", line 136, in <module>
    _cmd = "|| echo " + base64.b64encode(args.cmd.encode('utf8')) + "|base64 -d|bash"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: @vortext Please post a new question with your current code. Hint: the problem is very similar. You need to match the correct types.